# Ho do i set a path inside my dockerfile from the run command?

Tags: docker

I want to get the user:password@github... out of the dockerfile and into the docker run command.
i am new to docker and have a hard time figuring it out, can someone pls help me with this problem?

```
RUN mkdir -p /opt && \
      mkdir -p /home/rails && \
      cd /opt && \
      git clone --single-branch --branch main "https://User:Password@github.com/Example.git" example && \
      chmod +x ./example/entrypoint.sh && \
      cp ./example/entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
```

I looked at -e but that only lets me take a full line and i can not define when it gets executed.

Comment: `docker history` will be able to show you the username and password in clear text, if that's what you're asking.  It's usually better to run `git` commands from outside of Docker, maybe checking the Dockerfile into the repository and having it build whatever's currently checked out.  I'm a little unclear about what you mean by "getting it into the `docker run` command"; can you clarify what command you're running and what problem you're running into?

Comment: i wanted to add it as variable to the bash start command. sorry english  is not my first language.

Answer (score 0):

```
docker run -e GITHUB_USERNAME=user -e GITHUB_TOKEN=token your-image

single-branch --branch main "https://${GITHUB_USERNAME}:${GITHUB_TOKEN}@github.com/....
```

As always as soon as I asked here I found the answer online.